# Assembler DOS simple program

Tags: assembly

I have a program in Assembler DOS where I can enter a name and the program shows me the result. How can I add surname and age? Because it only shows me a name.

```
org 0x100
mov ah,9
mov dx, jak_masz
int 21h

mov ah,0ah
mov dx,imie
int 21h

mov ah , 9
mov dx, czesc
int 21h

mov ah,9
mov dx, imie + 2 
int 21h

mov ax , 4c00h
int 21h

jak_masz    db "Whats your name? $"
imie    db 20 
db 0 
times 22 db "$"

czesc    db 10,13,10,13, "Hi $"
```

Comment: It's better to ask your teacher. You already know how to take a step, it should be easy to Walk now.

Comment: Extend the code to enter, store and print two more strings (print them after getting all of the inputs). You might like to consider how you would convert the age string to an integer - and back to a string.